# JavaScript: Ways to open a new page in the same window

Tags: javascript, html, url, dom, location-href

```
location.href
location.replace
document.URL
```

As seen from other similar questions, can we consolidate all such possible methods?

Comment: URL is a replacement for the DOM Level 0 document.location.href property. However, document.location.href is settable, and document.URL is not.

Comment: @AshimSaha actually, it is window.location

Comment: see here what they say - https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Document_Object_Model_%28DOM%29/document.URL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var customURL = 'http://www.example.com';
window.location.href = customURL;
window.location.assign(customURL);

// Current page won't get saved in the history:
window.location.replace(customURL); 


// Gecko only:
window.document.location = customURL
```

See also:

- [MDN: `window.location`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location)
- [MDN: `window.document.location`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.location)
- [WhatWG: HTML5: 6.5.3 The Location interface](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/history.html#dom-location)